# Extract .json from a text file with arbitrary text

Tags: text-processing, json, jq

I have an output from  a program that give some arbitrary text, with .json stuff inside like:

```
blablablabla
blablab some more text

blablablabla
blablab some more text
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


blablablabla
blablab some more text


blablablabla
blablab some more text
```

I want to clean the text outside the .json to parse it with "jq".

I need only this text:

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

```
sed '/^{/,/^}/!d' < input
```

Would extract the portions of the file comprised between lines that start with `{` and the next line after that that starts with `}`.

```
pcregrep -Mo '(?s)(\{(?:[^{}"]++|"(?:\\.|[^"])*+"|(?1))*\})' < file
```

Would extract the pairs of top-level `{...}`s wherever they are, being smart enough to cope with input like `{"x":{"y":1}}` (nested `{}`) or `{ "x}" }` (`}` inside strings), or `{ "x\"}" }` (escaped quotes in strings).

If you don't have and can't install `pcregrep` (comes with the PCRE library), but you have GNU `grep`, built with PCRE, you can replace with `grep -zo` though that loads the whole file in memory. Or use `perl -l -0777 -ne 'print for m{regexp-above}g'`.